# How to subscribe to a store module

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am aware that in Vuex we can do `store.subscribe` and we pass a callback that is called on every change in the store.

In my app I have a store with many modules and would like to `subscribe` only to a specific Module and not have to have this kind of logic `if (mutation.type != thisModule.type) return;`.

Is it possible to subscribe only to some Modules? [Could not find it in the docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html).

Comment: You should be able to access each module through `this.$store.moduleName`. Try if there is a `subscribe` method - it should be working. I'm not able to test it but I remember something like that before..

Comment: @AndreyPopov That approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and came across with this question, according to this link:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-subscribe-and-modules/36049
Subscription is always global.

My work around is to check the mutation in each subscription:

Suppose you have a module 'yourmodule' for subscription, you can do:

```
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  if (mutation.type.startsWith("yourmodule")){
    //do your stuff here
  }
})
```

The mutation.type will give the actual mutation name, such as 'yourmodule/yourcommit', I use startswith() method to check because none of my modules starts the same, but you can use more accurate check for your own project.

Answer (score 3):

You may try that:

```
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  const pieces = mutation.type.split('/')
  if (pieces.length > 1) {
    const module = pieces[0]
  }
})
```

Comment: This works but it will be better to simplify more of your code.

Comment: const [ module, mutationName ] = mutation.type.split('/')

Answer (score -7):

Seems like you are over complicating it.
the best way to get access to a module, is to include it in the `modules` property of the store instance.

```
const moduleA = {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... }
}

const moduleB = {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    a: moduleA
    b: moduleB
  }
})
```

Comment: That is what I did. My question is: How do I subscribe **only** to mutations in `modules.a` for example?

Comment: Its not clear what u mean by "events" in the context of vuex.

Comment: I have not used the word `events` anywhere afaik. Do you think my question deserves a `-1`?